# Decode Base64InputStream from String and unzip it with GZIPInputStream in Java

Tags: java, base64, unzip

I am tryin to create simple app to decode the zipped data from string. In one textarea user will paste the zipped data after button click the data will be decoded and shown in another textarea.

If I use files, it works perfectly:

```
zis = new GZIPInputStream(new Base64InputStream(new FileInputStream(inZippedFile)));
```

where inZippedFile is file. Then result is saved to outputFile.

However, if I want to use string in InputStream it will never finish.

```
String input = "..."
InputStream in = IOUtils.toInputStream(input, "UTF-8");
zis = new GZIPInputStream(new Base64InputStream(in));
```

For IOUtils I am using common apache 2.4 jars. Anything what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Since Base64 represents binary data in ASCII, maybe your UTF-8 isn't relevant ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have it as a workaround, I use text editor to base64 decode and save it as zip. When I use UTF-8 it shows that zip is corrupted. It works when I set UTF-8 without BOM - but I was not able to manae that with code (tried also UTF-16 - still the same).

Answer (score 1):

The decoding and unzip the string data is working correctly, there was just mistake in parsing the data to corect form. This was causing the long run.
So this is working, no need to set the UTF-8:

```
new GZIPInputStream(new Base64InputStream(IOUtils.toInputStream(input)));
```